# Failed to resolve: com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+

Tags: android, google-maps, plugins, android-gradle-plugin

Trying to build [Google Maps Android API utility library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/), I have SDK 23 installed and all the [right SDK tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3qwh.jpg). At first when i imported the project I wasn't able to run it, the run button was greyed out. I then added "apply plugin: 'com.android.application'" to the top of gradle file. Then when i try to compile, I get the Failed to resolve: com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+ error in my build gradle(module: library).

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dependencies section in original android-maps-utils-master/demo/build.gradle contains:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    // Or, fetch from Maven:
//     compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
}
```

So:

1. You may use it as it is. Library android-maps-utils will be compiled from "*compile project(':library')*". It works for me. Or
2. You may comment "*compile project(':library')*", then uncomment "*compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'*" and the library will be downloaded from maven repository. But )

Gradle has no idea where it is. So you should add the followilg code:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

into the file android-maps-utils-master/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

This actually works:

Comment out the other dependencies where any google Api is called.
Specifically, firebase ( compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.1' ) and gms(  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1' ).
Now go for 'Sync Now'.

You may encounter some other error, like some value is missing.
Ignore the errors, uncomment the commented dependencies and Voila! It all has been figured out by our dear Gradle!